# "Directory not empty" when I try to remove a folder from trash

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, trash

I am going crazy:
**I can not delete a folder inside the trash of my external drive**.

The file path is `/Volumes/drive_name/.Trashes/501/dir_name/`

I tried

`sudo rm -R /Volumes/drive_name/.Trashes/501/dir_name/` and

`sudo rm -rf /Volumes/drive_name/.Trashes/501/dir_name/` 
in terminal but every time I get `Directory not empty`

The directory even shows up in my mac's trash when then the external drive is connected, but it does not empty:

[image]

How can I delete this folder from the trash?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to find the process using it (`fuser filename`)?  If that is not sufficient or you don't want to stop the process, you could try moving the file outside of trash.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Thanks for your suggestion, I moved the folder from trash to the drive, now trash is empty but I am still unable to remove the folder. I can not find the process that's using it.

Comment: Did you check `fuser filename`?  If that doesn't identify the process in question, simply restart the computer.